# How to pass Current User Credentials to .asmx Web Service

Tags: .net, sharepoint, asmx

**Situation:**

I created a web service that runs on my intranet web server.
The service has an operation that calls Microsoft SparePoint's lists.asmx web service.
The service also has a test operation.
When I invoke these services locally (visual studio) everything works great.

**Problem:**

When I deploy this web service to IIS on the web server the operation that calls lists.asmx fails with a 401 error. This occurs both when I run the service from IE when logged into the web server or if I'm running the service remotely (I have custom errors set to off, so I can see the 401 error)

**Desired Result:**

My web service should take the current user's credentials and pass them to the lists.asmx web service.

**Current Code:**
setting the Credentials in web service:

```
sharepointService.Lists listService = new sharePointService.Lists();
listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

setting the web reference in web.config:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyServices.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="sharepointService_Lists" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://sharepoint.myDomain.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </MyServices.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

**Other Information:**

The Test operation works when deployed on the IIS web server and returns two string for the following:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` = `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` = `IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0`

So it seems like the web serivce is using the user name of the IIS app pool, if this provides any helpful information.

**Solution:**

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I set the Windows Authentication to enabled in IIS and I was able to get HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name to return the actual current user. However, the lists.asmx web service is still returning 401 error

Comment: When I use the following code: `listService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserName", "myPassword", "myDomain");` the service works. However, I'm logged into the computer as `myUserName` I want these Credentials to be automatically passed to the lists.asmx service!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set authentication mode="Windows" in your web.config file under  section.

Comment: I tried placing it in the system.web section and it did not change the outcome. I also tried adding in `<identity impersonate="true"/>` and this generated the error: `An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.`

Comment: I put `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` into the web.config file to ignore the error and I still get the 401 error. Other ideas?

Comment: put this under **bold**<system.web>**bold** section

Comment: yup, I did that, however, and now I can get the current user in the HttpContextas I noted in my comment. But when passing the default network Credentials the service returns a 401 error.

Comment: how are you passing the default network credentials? could you please post your code?

Comment: The code is in my original question `listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

Comment: Are you trying to access any other resource through your web service which requries authorization? For example sql server or file folder etc? 
Try to just return request information back and see if request and response communication is working fine.